# How can RestSharp deserialize this Xml?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, deserialization, restsharp

Is it possible to get RestSharp to deserialize this Xml snippet, into a single class, instead of two classes?

```
<shippingInfo>
    <shippingServiceCost currencyId="AUD">58.02</shippingServiceCost>
    <shippingType>Flat</shippingType>
    <shipToLocations>Worldwide</shipToLocations>
</shippingInfo>
```

Notice the first element `shippingServiceCost` ? it has an attribute there. Normally, I would just create a child class called `ShippingServiceCost` and add two properties in there: `CurrentId` and `Value`.

But it it possible to have the CurrencyId value in a property, in the main class `ShippingInfo` ?

Answer (score 0):

The way I would do it, could be:

1. crafting a small XSLT file that does what you want to transform the orginal xml to the new structure
2. extend the default RestSharp XmlSerializer to apply the XSLT transformation after the normal serialization output
3. register the new XmlSerializer to the restsharp client